# Wait for previous blocks to finish processing before continuing

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a process which looks like this.

1. Get a set of CSV files from a folder
2. Read the CSV files, and store the contents in a database
3. Read the data from the database and perform some more processing.

The reason for the separation of steps 2 & 3 is to separate issues involved with reading the files from issues involved with processing the files.

I can model this with three dataflow blocks. The problem I have is that I don't want block 3 to start until all files have been persisted to the database. I need some way of determining that all the files that were picked up in block 1 have been processed by block 2. Block 2 will have its `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set to `Unbounded` - I want them processed in parallel.

I considered using `Encapsulate` on the first two blocks, but I don't think that would work. Perhaps I need some kind of `Batchblock`, but the batches are not all going to be the same size.

How can I do this? Do I need to create my own block type?

Comment: Do you have to read all the data from the database at the same time, or can you read them file by file, or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't fit a single TDF flow since step #2 doesn't pass items to step #3 which starts after the previous ones already completed.

You should have 2 separate flows. The first reads from the folder and stores in the database and the second reads from the database and starts processing. You can wait for the first flow to complete by awaiting the `Completion` property:

```
var reader = // Create #1 block
var dbFiller = // Create #2 block

reader.LinkTo(dbFiller, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }); // Link both blocks with Completion Propagation

reader.Post( // Queue up work for reader

await reader.Completion; // Asynchronously wait for previous steps to complete

var processor = // Create #3 block

processor.Post( // Queue up work for processor
```

Comment: To do it this way, though, I would need to Complete() the reader, wouldn't I? Which is missing from the code above. I don't want to do that, since this is a repeatable process, and I want to reuse the pipeline.

Comment: @user1158174 but you say you want the processing to start only after the previous finished. What do you mean finished if it's not completed...

Comment: Yes. I guess that's really the question, isn't it? Step 1 will run once every, say, ten minutes. When it executes, it may find ten files. I want all of these processed by step 2 before step 3 starts. So when I say finished, I mean "finished the current batch of files". This is where I'm getting stuck, because Dataflow doesn't offer this out of the box. The BatchBlock is the closest, but it needs batches of a specific size, which is not what I have.

Comment: @user1158174 TDF doesn't offer that at all. I recommend you use my answer.. but call it every 10 minutes and wait for the whole cycle to complete. Then wait for 10 minutes and do it again.. etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Guess I was hoping for a way to encapsulate that behaviour in a custom block or something.

Comment: @user1158174 It doesn't fit. a TDF block only completes once. What you're looking for are phases...

Comment: @user1158174 You could create a block that receives a "ping", creates blocks for steps #1 and #2, and when #2 completes, sends out a "ping" to the following block. But I'm not sure that would be actually useful.